# Odata issue C# -Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.OData'

Tags: c#, dll, odata, .net-assembly

Trying to debug my project I am getting the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.AspNet.OData' or one of its dependencies. Strong name signature could not be verified.  The assembly may have been tampered with, or it was delay signed but not fully signed with the correct private key. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131045)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4sMEJ.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried to clean the solution and to build it again?

Comment: I deleted Bin and Obj folders of the project .Nothing work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.